# How to switch the Connection on a Tableau Data Source

Tags: tableau-api

There are two Connections for a given DataSource. I am uncertain how to select the second one (`Vertica-GemScoring`) to be "active".

[image]

In the meantime I have created a separate `Data Source` for `Vertica`: *that* does work.  But then what does it mean to have 2 connections for one Data Source - and how to choose which is one is "active" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two connections on this screen is indicative that you are intending to join the two together.

Starting in Tableau 10, a user can perform '[Cross Database Joins](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/7/integrate-your-data-cross-database-joins-56724)'. This differs from the previously only available method of 'Blending' datasources.

As far as which datasource is the primary (as opposed to 'active') on this screen, it only depends on which is added first.

If your intention is to merely have a dashboard which references two different datasources, you would then add separate datasources as you have done. If you have a common field which you would like to join the two datasources together, Cross Database Joins or Blending should be used.